# Is it possible to create a list of values of member fields using iterators?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, iterator, std

Consider the following struct

```cpp
struct Pair 
{
   int a;
   std::string b;
};
```

I have a `std::vector<Pair> pairs` but I want a `std::vector<std::string> listOfBFromPairs` which contains all the values of b from the list of pairs.

I would like to do this in a one-liner.

I have used OpenGL before and I have previously created a struct, specified a starting point

```
pairs.begin() + offsetof(Pair, b)
```

and given a stride length (the size of the pair object in memory) and the number of things I want to parse and it has done what I am after here.

Is this possible here too using c++ iterators?

The specific use case I have is I want to make an *unordered set* of Vulkan extension names but Vulkan returns structs which contain the extension name as a member. I will then use the unordered set to check against extensions my application would like to use.

Comment: Do you care about duplicates? If you don't then this is trivial. If you do then your either need to pick a `set` instead of  a `vector` or you will need to remove the duplicates afterwards, but then it's no longer a one liner.

Comment: If you want an unordered_set then why are you creating a vector? Just create the unordered_set directly. That would be a one liner.

Comment: The vulkan API returns an array of structs. The glfw API returns an array of strings. They're guaranteed to be unique. I'm using an unordered set because I want O(1) lookup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want a `std::vector<std::string> listOfBFromPairs` which contains
> all the values of `b` from the list of `pairs`.
>
> I would like to do this in a one-liner?

Sure you can. You can use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) from [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) header like this

```
#include <algorithm> // std::transform
#include <iterator>  // std::back_inserter

std::vector<Pair> pairs;
std::vector<std::string> listOfBFromPairs;
listOfBFromPairs.reserve(pairs.size()); // reserve the memory for unwanted reallocations

std::transform(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(),
   std::back_inserter(listOfBFromPairs), [](const Pair& pair) { return pair.b; }
);
```

---

However in case you need `listOfBFromPairs` with no duplicates using `unordered_set`, you need to create a `std::unordered_set<std::string> listOfBFromPairs;` not a vector of strings. In that case, you need to insert the strings to unordered_set using [`std::inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter).

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <algorithm> // std::transform
#include <iterator>  // std::inserter

std::vector<Pair> pairs;
std::unordered_set<std::string> listOfBFromPairs;

std::transform(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(),
   std::inserter(listOfBFromPairs, listOfBFromPairs.end()), [](const auto& pair) { return pair.b; }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for a one-liner, here's a Boost approach (not very readable IMHO):

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <functional>

const std::vector<Pair> src;

const auto listOfBFromPairs = boost::copy_range<std::vector<std::string>>(src | boost::adaptors::transformed(std::mem_fn(&Pair::b)));
```

If the target container is e.g. a `std::unordered_set`, change the last line to

```
const auto listOfBFromPairs = boost::copy_range<std::unordered_set<std::string>>(src | boost::adaptors::transformed(std::mem_fn(&Pair::b)));
```

(where only the instantiation of `copy_range` changed). You can achieve something similar with C++20 ranges.